# Change Component's content during rendering phase when loading its model fails

Tags: wicket

I have a widget components with simple markup inheritance like so

### AbstractWidget

```
<wicket:panel>
    <wicket:child />

    <div wicket:enclosure="editButton" class="widget-edit-wrapper">
        <button wicket:id="editButton" type="button" class="widget-edit">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
        </button>
        <div style="display:none;">
            <div wicket:id="editPanel" class="widget-settings"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</wicket:panel>
```

### LabelWidget

```
<wicket:extend>
    <div wicket:id="container" class="label-widget flex-container">
        <div wicket:id="label"></div>
    </div>
</wicket:extend>
```

Now imagine the label content is taken from a loadable detachable model and loading the model throws an Exception.

I need to show some feedback to the user on this 'broken' widget component. Is there a way to replace the whole child's content when loading its model throws an Exception?

Note that `LabelWidget` is just one from many `AbstractWidget` childs so I need to solve this in the `AbstractWidget` and I also need to preserve all elements from the `AbstractWidget` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using a smarter model - a model that delegates to the original one and try/catches if it throws an exception. In case of an exception you will need to return an "empty" model object, where "empty" would mean different things for your different use cases.

Your smart model could implement `IComponentAssignedModel` so that it knows the `Component` it is used in. This way in the `catch` clause you can do `component.error("...")`. In `AbstractWidget` you should add a `FeedbackPanel` that will render the error message. The specialization widget, like `LabelWidget`, will render as "empty" (whatever this means for it) by using the fallback model.